# Maze: Emoji Portals 3: Konchog's RE-Revenge

Tags: visual, mazes, emoji, network

This puzzle is now revised, fixed, checked, and double-checked.

It is also the last (certainly for the time being) of this class of emoji-portal 'classic' mazes.
Portals are always in adjacent levels and at the same location. *Do not be confused by apparent duplicates that are in non-adjacent levels / positions! They are doppelgängers*

Your mission: Start at "**Start**", and travel to "**Exit**"..

[image: Emoji Portals: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No shortcuts for this one :P

> [image]
>
> Much harder this time!